How to define specific colors for Errorbars in R using ggplot?
I want to generate a plot (copies vs. measurement) with data from two machines (A and B). For each machine, I calculated a linear model to display a regression line as well as the datapoints and the errorbars for each point.
The data looks as follows:
df <- data.frame(
  machine = c("A","A","A", "A","B","B","B"),
  copies = c(105.25,52.63,5.26,1.05,105.26,52.63,5.26),
  measurement = c(28.74,29.86,32.74,34.98,32.06,33.25,37.29),
  std.dev = c(0.33,0.44,0.30,2.15,0.28,0.29,0.84)
)

The linear models were generated with:
lin.mod.A <- lm(measurement ~ log10(copies), data = df[df$machine=="A",])
lin.mod.B <- lm(measurement ~ log10(copies), data = df[df$machine=="B",])

And the code I tried to generate the plot:
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=log10(copies), y=measurement, col=machine)) + 
  # Draw regression line for machine A
  geom_abline(intercept = lin.mod.A$coefficients[1], slope = lin.mod.A$coefficients[2], color="deepskyblue", lty="dashed", lwd=1) +
  # Draw regression line for machine B
  geom_abline(intercept = lin.mod.B$coefficients[1], slope = lin.mod.B$coefficients[2], color="darkorange", lty="dashed", lwd=1) +
  # add errorbars
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=measurement-std.dev, ymax=measurement+std.dev, col=machine), width=.05) +
  # add points
  geom_point(aes(col=machine), size = 2) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.text=element_text(size=13),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
print(p)

This code results in the following plot:

The problem with the plot is, that the colors of the points and errobars do not match the colors of the regression lines. I want everything from machine A (line, points and errorbars) to be "deepskyblue" and the data from machine B to be "darkorange".
I also tried to define a vector as follows: cols <- c('A' = 'deepskyblue', 'B' = 'darkorange') to use in the col arguments of geom_point() and geom_errorbar() but this did also not change the colors of the points and errorbars.
I think it should be possible to map all elements (line, points and errorbars) to the same color but I cannot manage to do it. Does anyone have an a suggestion how this could be done?

scale_color_manual(values = c('A' = 'deepskyblue', 'B' = 'darkorange')) adding this works for me, as shown here:  https://i.sstatic.net/xFuDYLdi.png
